# RDP started failing on Ubuntu 16

Tags: remote-desktop

I have been using RDP from windows 7 into my Ub 16 PC for quite a while.
Just recently (possibly as a result of standard updates and a reboot) the connection is failing. 
After starting win client and putting in username/pw the remote window opens and in the black 'console' I get:

```
connecting to sesman ip xxx port 3350
sesman connect ok
sending login info to session manager, please wait...
xrdp_mm_process_login_response; login successful for displa
started connecting
connecting to xxx 5910
tcp connected
security level is 2 (1=none, 2=standard)
password failed
error - problem connecting
```

I get the same result if connecting to myself from my Ub PC directly with remmina (for testing)